# Killing a thread in java android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, deprecated

I have an application where i need to call 3 methods in 3 seperate threads and kill them afterwards. According to the Javadoc i noticed that thread `stop()` and even `destroy()` has been deprecated. its like I start one thread after the other and then kill similarly one after the other. Is there a particular way to kill the threads because I cant use the deprecated methods

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks again

Comment: Can you not just wait for them to complete using `Thread.join()`?

Comment: Taking a step back, do you really need a thread of your own, or can you use a thread pool via an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)?

Comment: ...the Android threadpool executor reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't kill threads. You call [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29), and then react to the `interrupted` status or `InterruptedException` *within the thread that's being interrupted*. Or, you use a `volatile` flag. See [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for background and more info.

Even better, use a thread pool / executor instead of raw threads, as suggested in comments.

Comment: After the comments made by weston and Joolan i found it very important to use a thread pool bcause it reduces the overhead of starting threads one after the other. I found a good example for it as well and have  alook at this and it will be very helpful for anyone. therefore here is an example of its implementation 

http://apachejava.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/java-thread-pool-easy-tutorial.html

I have accepted Joolans answer and even westons comments helped me to read through the threadpool

Answer (score 0):

Terminating a rogue thread in a way that works every time everywhere is pretty much impossible.

If you can control the source code of the running threads, you must add a method with which you can stop the thread when you need to. Basically this method changes a boolean variable and the thread checks that value periodically to see whether or not it can continue.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    // Set this to true when thread must stop.
    private boolean mStopRequested = false;
    public void run() {
        while (mStopRequested == false) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you call a 3rd party libraries that do not provide such a method, then you are out of luck and have to resort to ugly kludges. Once I had to kill a long running 3rd party library call by deleting a file that was accessed by the library (it threw a FileNotFoundException and exited). And that only worked on Unix systems.

Your mileage will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use join method until the receiver finishes its execution and dies or the specified timeout expires, whatever happens first.

```
thread1.join(1);
thread2.join(2);
thread3.join(3);
```

You must handle the exception.